# Allocating treatment to the each subjects

Tags: r, loops

I have four strata (`stratum1`, `stratum2`, `stratum3`, and `stratum4`) and I want to perform this code for each stratum in a loop and add the variable to a data frame

```
Strat1_Stratum1_Treat <- block_ra(blocks = ProjectData1$Stratum1,
                                  prob = .5, conditions = c("A","B"))
```

[check the nature of the data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5O9xt.png)

Comment: It would be helpful if you could share the smallest amount of data to reproduce the question

Comment: Please tell us what the package you use. Nobody knows where the function `block_ra` comes from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Example Data

```
blocks <- sample(0:1, 40, TRUE)
data <- as.data.frame(matrix(blocks, 10, 4))
data

#    V1 V2 V3 V4
# 1   0  1  1  1
# 2   0  0  0  0
# 3   1  1  0  1
# 4   0  0  0  1
# 5   1  1  1  1
# 6   1  1  0  1
# 7   0  0  0  0
# 8   1  0  0  0
# 9   0  0  1  0
# 10  0  0  0  0
```

Use `lapply()` to conduct a function for each variable.

```
data[5:8] <- lapply(data, block_ra, prob = .5, conditions = c("A", "B"))
data

#    V1 V2 V3 V4 V1.1 V2.1 V3.1 V4.1
# 1   0  1  1  1    A    A    B    B
# 2   0  0  0  0    B    B    B    B
# 3   1  1  0  1    A    A    A    A
# 4   0  0  0  1    B    A    B    B
# 5   1  1  1  1    B    B    A    A
# 6   1  1  0  1    A    B    B    A
# 7   0  0  0  0    B    A    B    A
# 8   1  0  0  0    B    B    A    B
# 9   0  0  1  0    A    A    B    A
# 10  0  0  0  0    A    B    A    B
```

Comment: Awesome it worked perfectly